# Is there a limit for the max charger supply current for this power bank?

Tags: power

To charge [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/0b5b/0900766b81617694.pdf) power bank 5V supply is needed through micro USB. It says FOR the power bank the charge current: ≤ 2200 mA.

What does that indicate for the power supply max current which charges this power bank? Does that mean one should use a 5V supply/adapter with Imax>2.2A or Imax<2.2A?

(Normally when we use a supply for a device we apply exact voltage with minimum current the device needs or more. For example a device with input sepcs 5V 2A would work fine with a supply rated for 5V 4A. But it wouldnt work for 5V 0.5A)

But in this case it is not that clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power bank should internally limit the charging current to a safe level, and automatically ramp the current down when approaching a fully charged state.

Therefore you can safely use a 5V 3A power supply.

Comment: How about using 5V 500mA supply. Would that load the power supply a lot?

Comment: It’s har to tell without knowing more about its internal design. But my guess is that it should be designed to be plugged into a ‘standard’ USB 2.0 socket which is only required to deliver 500mA.